# v-date-picker does not close on tab out

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm fairly new to vuetify and vue in general. The problem I'm facing is that when I click on a datepicker, the calendar pops up and when I tab out, the cursor moves to the next input field but the calendar does not close.
I want it to close automatically on tab out.

I tried setting `close-on-content-click="true"` instead of `false` but to no avail. I'm not sure what else to try.

Here is a codepen I found vuetify documentation that has similar implementation and behavior as my application. [codepen](https://codepen.io/Milind452/pen/YzEzqKr)

Thank you for any inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this @keydown.tab='menu1 = false' in v-text-field

Comment: Thanks @Nilesh... It works. However I'm not really sure what's happening. Could you explain what this line does?

Comment: keydown.tab is directive is a Vue.js directive used to add an event listener to a button in the keyboard . we can execute a function when we press the associated key.

Comment: Hi @Nilesh I've run into another problem now. The calendar pop up closes as expected but since the next field is also a date field, on tab out, the second calendar pop-up should also open. But that does not happen even though the 2nd date field comes into focus.

Comment: @keydown.tab='menu1 = false,menu2=true' in v-text-field 1st and in 2nd text-field @keydown.tab='menu1 = true,menu2=false'. better to write a method and call them on keydown.tab  like @keydown.tab='updateMenuModel()' , updateMenuModel() { this.menu1 = false; this.menu2 = true;}

Comment: hey @MilindMohapatra you can try this,i think it can solve your problem

Comment: Thanks @Nilesh It does help me. I was able to close a bug with this.

Answer (score 0):

`close-on-content-click` is for mouse clicks and does not apply to keyboard actions. You need to explicitly toggle the v-menu model when the input loses focus.

To close the menu when whenever the input field loses focus I would attach the toggle to the blur event. You can do this by replacing the `@blur` listener to a method, in which you will set the menu model to false.

```html
<v-text-field
  v-model="dateFormatted"
  label="Date"
  hint="MM/DD/YYYY format"
  persistent-hint
  prepend-icon="mdi-calendar"
  v-bind="attrs"
  @blur="updateDate"
  v-on="on"
/>
```

```js
updateDate(event) {
  // This is the same value as dateFormatted,
  // you don't need to say this.dateFormatted like in your codepen.
  const value = event.target.value;
  this.date = this.parseDate(value);
  this.menu1 = false;
}
```

"Destructuring" is JS good practice instead of randomly named variables or verbosity so I would write the first line as:
`const { value } = event.target;`

If you were passing additional variables into `updateDate` method you would need to write it as `updateDate($event, variable)` but if not, `$event` as first parameter is a given.